# declaration file for custom hook vue3 composable

Tags: typescript, laravel, vuejs3, composable

I have a laravel, vue3 and typescript project.

in the users module, UsersGrid, I have a custom composable, useUser , I want to type it, but every way I try, an error always comes up

as a custom hook ( composable ) i cant npm install @types/XYZ

tsconfig in root :

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    // As long as you are using a build tool, we recommend you to author and ship in ES modules.
    // Even if you are targeting Node.js, because
    //  - `CommonJS` is too outdated
    //  - the ecosystem hasn't fully caught up with `Node16`/`NodeNext`
    // This recommendation includes environments like Vitest, Vite Config File, Vite SSR, etc.
    "module": "ESNext",

    // We expect users to use bundlers.
    // So here we enable some resolution features that are only available in bundlers.
    "moduleResolution": "bundler",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    // `allowImportingTsExtensions` can only be used when `noEmit` or `emitDeclarationOnly` is set.
    // But `noEmit` may cause problems with solution-style tsconfigs:
    // <https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/49844>
    // And `emitDeclarationOnly` is not always wanted.
    // Considering it's not likely to be commonly used in Vue codebases, we don't enable it here.

    // Required in Vue projects
    "jsx": "preserve",
    "jsxImportSource": "vue",

    // `"noImplicitThis": true` is part of `strict`
    // Added again here in case some users decide to disable `strict`.
    // This enables stricter inference for data properties on `this`.
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "strict": true,

    // <https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-5-0/#verbatimmodulesyntax>
    // Any imports or exports without a type modifier are left around. This is important for `<script setup>`.
    // Anything that uses the type modifier is dropped entirely.
    "verbatimModuleSyntax": true,

    // A few notes:
    // - Vue 3 supports ES2016+
    // - For Vite, the actual compilation target is determined by the
    //   `build.target` option in the Vite config.
    //   So don't change the `target` field here. It has to be
    //   at least `ES2020` for dynamic `import()`s and `import.meta` to work correctly.
    // - If you are not using Vite, feel free to overwrite the `target` field.
    "target": "ESNext",
    // For spec compilance.
    // `true` by default if the `target` is `ES2020` or higher.
    // Explicitly set it to `true` here in case some users want to overwrite the `target`.
    "useDefineForClassFields": true,

    // Recommended
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    // See <https://github.com/vuejs/vue-cli/pull/5688>
    "skipLibCheck": true,
  }
}
```

UsersGrid :

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ag-grid-vue :style="gridStyle" suppressHorizontalScroll="true" :gridOptions="gridOptions" :class="gridMode"
            :columnDefs="columnDefs.value" :rowData="rowData" :loadingOverlayComponent="CardOverlay">
        </ag-grid-vue>
    </div>
</template> 

<script setup lang="ts">

import { ref, watch, computed, onMounted } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router';
import { AgGridVue } from "ag-grid-vue3";
import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n'
import { gridOptions, gridStyle } from "../../helpers/gridSettings";
import ActionButtons from '../../components/grids/ActionButtons.vue'
import CardOverlay from '../../components/general/CardOverlay.vue'
import Tr from "../../helpers/translation";
import useUser from '../../composables/useUser' // Could not find a declaration file for module '../../composables/useUser'. 'c:/Users/kaue.zuquetto/Desktop/Dev/Portal/resources/js/composables/useUser.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
import { useStore } from 'vuex'

import type { User, ColDef } from '../../../../types'



const { t, locale } = useI18n()
const store = useStore()
const router = useRouter()
const gridMode = ref('ag-theme-alpine')
const columnDefs = ref()
const {
    getAllData: getUsers,
    deleteData: deleteUser,
    rowData,
} = useUser();

const details = (id: number) => {
    router.push(Tr.i18nRoute({ name: 'user.read', params: { id } }))
}

const i18nGrid = () => {
    columnDefs.value = [
        [],
        { headerName: 'ID', field: 'id', flex: 1 },
        { headerName: t('user.grid.colName'), field: 'name', flex: 3 },
        { headerName: t('user.grid.colEmail'), field: 'email', flex: 3 },
        { headerName: t('grid.created_at'), field: 'created_at', flex: 3 },
        { headerName: t('grid.updated_at'), field: 'updated_at', flex: 3 },
        {
            headerName: '',
            flex: 1.5,
            sortable: false,
            filter: false,
            cellRenderer: ActionButtons,
            cellRendererParams: function () {
                return {
                    details: details,
                    delete: deleteUser,
                    id: arguments[0].data.id,
                    buttons: ['details', 'delete']
                }
            },
        },
    ] as ColDef<User>[];
}

const options = computed(() => {
    return store.getters["preferences/options"]
})

watch(options, () => {
    gridMode.value = store.state.preferences.options.grid
})

watch(locale, () => {
    i18nGrid()
})

onMounted(() => {
    i18nGrid()
    getUsers()
    gridMode.value = store.state.preferences.options.grid
})

</script>
```

my useUser composable :

```
import { ref, reactive } from 'vue'
import { useRouter } from 'vue-router'
import useSwal from '../helpers/swal'
import Tr from '../helpers/translation'
import { gridOptions, gridStyle } from "../helpers/gridSettings"

const { confirm_delete_swal, toast_success, toast_error } = useSwal()

const useUser = (userID = null) => {

    const router = useRouter()
    const user = ref({})
    const isLoading = ref(false)
    const processing = ref(false)
    const errors = ref(false)
    const rowData = ref(null)

    const getAllData = async () => {
        try {
            const response = await axios.get('/api/users')
            const { status } = response
            if (status === 200) {
                rowData.value = response.data.data
                rowData.value.sort((a, b) => b.id - a.id)
            } else {
                console.log('ERROR STATUS:  ' + response.status)
                toast_error()
            }
        } catch (e) {
            gridOptions.api.hideOverlay()
            gridOptions.api.showNoRowsOverlay()
            toast_error()
            console.log(e)
        }
    }

    const getData = async () => {
        try {
            isLoading.value = true
            const url = '/api/user/' + userID + '/read';
            const response = await axios.get(url)
            if (response.status === 200) {
                const { data } = response.data
                user.value = data
            } else {
                console.log('ERROR STATUS:  ' + response.status)
                toast_error()
            }
        } catch (e) {
            toast_error()
            console.log(e)
        } finally {
            isLoading.value = false
        }
    }

    const createData = async (formData) => {
        try {
            processing.value = true
            const response = await axios.post('/api/user/create', formData)
            if (response.status === 200) {
                const { data } = response.data
                errors.value = {}
                router.push(Tr.i18nRoute({ name: 'user.read', params: { id: data.id } }))
                toast_success()
            } else {
                toast_error()
                console.log('ERROR STATUS:  ' + response.status)
            }
        } catch (e) {
            toast_error()
            console.log(e)
            if (e.response && e.response.data.errors) {
                errors.value = e.response.data.errors
            }
        } finally {
            processing.value = false
        }
    }

    const updateData = async (formData, userRoles) => {
        try {
            processing.value = true
            const response = await axios.put('/api/user/' + userID + '/update', formData)
            if (response.status === 200) {
                const { data } = response.data
                errors.value = {}
                router.replace(Tr.i18nRoute({ name: 'user.read', params: { id: data } }))
                userRoles.assignRoles()
            } else {
                toast_error()
                console.log('ERROR STATUS:  ' + response.status)
            }
        } catch (e) {
            toast_error()
            console.log(e)
            toast_error()
            if (e.response && e.response.data.errors) {
                errors.value = e.response.data.errors
            }
        } finally {
            processing.value = false
        }
    }

    const deleteData = async (id) => {
        try {
            const { isConfirmed } = await confirm_delete_swal(id)
            if (isConfirmed) {
                const response = await axios.delete('/api/user/' + id + '/delete')
                const { status } = response
                if (status == 200) {
                    getAllData()
                    toast_success()
                } else {
                    toast_error()
                }
            }
        } catch (e) {
            toast_error()
            console.log(e)
            if (e.response && e.response.data.errors) {
                errors.value = e.response.data.errors
            }
        }
    }

    userID ? getData() : ''

    return {
        getAllData,
        rowData,
        getData,
        user,
        createData,
        updateData,
        deleteData,
        isLoading,
        processing,
        errors,
    }
}
export default useUser;
```

how can create a declaration file form my useUser hook ? its always complaining about not being a module, or not being callable

useUser.d.ts :

//Could not find a declaration file for module '../../composables/useUser'.  implicitly has an 'any' type.ts(7016)

```
declare module 'useUser' {
    export function useUser(): unknown
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless otherwise configured, TypeScript files (or components) expect only typed imports. Your composable is a `.js` file. You can change this behavior and allow JS imports with the [allowJs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#allowJs) compiler option in tsconfig

```js
"compilerOptions": {
     "allowJs": true,
}
```

Alternatively, you can rewrite your composable in TypeScript.

Comment: I understand, but how does it work, in the case of some libs?

for example, I use vue-i18n , there are files vue-i18n.d.js and vue-i18n.d.ts, one with just a declaration ( declaration file ) and the other just with JS, how can I make a declaration file like this? Is it possible without having to migrate the useUser file to .ts?

in advance, thank you for your help

Comment: Most TS libraries are also JS compatible because of a compile step that splits the typescript into .js and .d.ts files, and these files are what get published.  The two files can be used together in TS projects, or the .js file can be used alone in JS projects. It's usually easier to just code in TS and let the [compile step](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#declaration) create the declaration file, but you can also create one [manually](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/introduction.html) if you want, or use a [tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/dts-gen)

Comment: Thank you very much, I appreciate you taking the time to help me, I managed to understand better, I thought it was mandatory to have both types of file. Now I'm going to migrate js to ts